# OpenGL glcolor for loop

Tags: c, opengl, for-loop

i am trying to draw a lorenz attractor where the color changes throughout the attractor. i have written the following for loop which calculates the attractor points.

```
    float x = 1, y = 1, z = 1;
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);

    int i;    
    for (i=0; i < initialIterations; i++) {
        glColor3d(0,i/50000,1);
        // compute a new point using the lorenz attractor equations
        float dx = sigma*(y-x);
        float dy = x*(r-z) - y;
        float dz = x*y - b*z;

        // save the new point
        x = x + dx*dt;
        y = y + dy*dt;
        z = z + dz*dt;        

        glVertex3f(x/50,y/50,z/50);
    }
    glEnd();
```

i am using the `glcolor` at the top of the code to change the color as a function of `i`. However i do not see the result i want, all i get is one solid color. i know the color works like a state machine but i need to find a way to change the color throughout.

Comment: you are using a deprecated approach, i suggest to not even discuss this code since it's not even granted to work with a modern OpenGL environment, start with OpenGL 3.0+ and the programmable pipeline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing integer division : `i/50000`, so it's always 0.

Try `i/50000.0`